# how i can work the youtube api in my vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi gangs actually I wont to use  a youtube api inside my project  but after that I put my script  inside my index html  and I put this code in my component

```js
  methods: {
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      window.player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            playlist: 'taJ60kskkns,FG0fTKAqZ5g'
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize
        } 
    });
```

I have this errors `YT` is not defined `no-undef`

> `42:22  error  'initialize' is not defined.`

Comment: where are you importing `YT` and defining `initialize`, when are you calling `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`?

Comment: I import YT when I imported  the youtube api (inside my index html) and inizialitze in the same mode

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You will have several issues with Youtube Player, but it's possible to work with it as long as you follow the strict rules

an error is to append `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` to anywhere that is not the `window` object, so you really need to start that function in the window, for example:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
  console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady")
};
```

as you can't have this function inside a method, you can do the other way around... have that function call a method inside your Vue Object

```js
var vueApp = new Vue({ 
  ...
  methods: {
    initYoutube() {}
  }
})

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
  console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady")
  vueApp.initYoutube()
};
```

and with that small trick you can use the Youtube API like normal:

```js
<div id="app">
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>

var vueApp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      player: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    initYoutube() {
      const _ = this;
      console.log("initYoutube");
      this.player = new YT.Player("player", {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: "Xa0Q0J5tOP0",
        events: {
          onReady: _.onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: _.onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    },
    onPlayerReady(evt) {
      console.log("Player ready");
      evt.target.playVideo();
    },
    onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
      console.log("Player state changed", evt);
    }
  }
});

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
  console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");
  vueApp.initYoutube();
};
```

Here's a [working example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/dyYPBrW?editors=1010)

*(sorry about Veutify, but my VueJs CodePen template set's all up automagically, just use without the `vuetify: new Vuetify(),` line)* :)

Comment: but I using a vue cli sorry, but I m confuse

Comment: try a component then, for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-youtube

Comment: @balexandre this should be the accepted answer. Got the YT Player to work in my vue component based off your post/fiddle. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube Iframe works slightly differently than you've implemented.

1. First, you have to have the youtube iframe api script in your project index.html.
2. Inside the component where you're trying use the iframe, implement the code like the following example:

```js
<template>
<div class="playlist">
  <!-- this is the div where the IFrame API will inject the iframe content into -->
  <div id="video"></div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      player: null
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = this.initPlayer
  },
  methods: {
    initPlayer() {
      const videoEl = document.getElementById("video")
      this.player = new YT.Player(videoEl, {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        videoId: 'Xa0Q0J5tOP0',
        playerVars: {},
        events: {
            onReady: this.onInitialize()
        } 
      });
    },
    onInitialize() { console.log("Initialized") }
  }
}
</script>
```

I've noticed you've used items like `color` and `playlist` in the `playerVars` option while creating the player. I am sorry, but these variables are not valid. You can see the available player variables options at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Here is an example component I have created for a similar use case. In the component, API loading is done using promises so you will never face issues like `YT undefined`. You can check it out at https://github.com/kiranparajuli589/vue3-ytframe/blob/master/lib/VueYtframe.vue
Give it a star, if it helps :)