# Where do I put script tags when I use Youtube api in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried putting the script tags in index.html but that didn't work because it said that gapi is undefined in my Vue component which is in another file

This is an example of what I want to use

```js
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.search.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet"
      ],
      "q": "boo"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

However I want to have my script tag in an index.html and the function in a vue component

Comment: *However I want to have my script tag in an index.html and the function in a vue component* - then do that, or explain why you can't

Comment: My post mentions why putting a script tag in index.html isn't helping, when I do that `gapi` object which is in my function in a vue component is undefined

Comment: have you read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164818/how-i-can-work-the-youtube-api-in-my-vue-project)

Comment: After reading this I'm confused because they have created a new vue object but the way they did it isn't how I've worked with vue so far. I usually create a new vue file and have <template> <script> and <style> tag. I don't know how to get the vue object since I don't create a new one